# Localizing app and change FlowDirection in runtime in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, localization

In the application there's an option in the settings page that lets the user to choose his preferred language (English /Arabic) 
When one selected I want to change the culture and the FlowDirection.
I change culture by setting the culture property of the resource file. But 
 is this doable in runtime: when the user changes the language, the application localization and FlowDirection changes accordingly instantly?

In [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left) there's this tip:

> You should only set the FlowDirection property on initial layout.
>   Changing this value at runtime causes an expensive layout process that
>   will affect performance.

So is there a safe way to accomplish this..  I see this option in many applications I use personally!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a safe way to accomplish this?

As the docs said , changing this value at runtime causes an expensive layout process that will affect performance.

However,you can implement it in native platforms by using DependencyService.

> in iOS

**Solution:** When you create a new control or page in Forms, create a `CustomRenderer` in iOS . And add a notification which inform the control change the UI. When you changing the value ,send the notification and all the pages and controls will refresh the UI. That's how most apps are implemented in native iOS . Due to iOS system optimization ,it will not causes an expensive layout process .But you have to do more.

> in Android

**Solution:** Do the same thing in Android will affect performance.So you can restart the `MainActivity` after you changing the value.